# Tag rename/alias request: [memsql] -> [singlestore]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

MemSQL was [officially renamed to Singlestore](https://www.singlestore.com/blog/revolution/) in October of 2020.

I'd like to request to rename the [memsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memsql) tag to [singlestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singlestore), and add a synonym [memsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memsql) → [singlestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singlestore).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done. I also approved your edits to the tag wiki and excerpt; thanks for being thorough!